# Alternative to always referencing to parents and children to modify DOM when using 'this'

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

**I notice that I'm always using `this` for everything**, when I need to share behaviour between components.

### Example

I was creating a *customised* file input component, and I had to return the file that was added by the user with JS therefore. But there were  **three** inputs, and I need to create a function **that would be shared among them**, so it could not be specific nor unique. It should work for all of'em.

```
var setFilename = function () {
  // get element I want

  var input    = this
  var filepath  = input.value
  var m         = filepath.match(/([^\/\\]+)$/)
  var filename  = m[1]
  var spanLabel  = input.parentNode.querySelector('.input')
  // apply to element I wanted to get
  spanLabel.innerHTML = filename;
}
```

#### The problem

Notice the had work just to reach the element I want *in a general way*. I used `parentNode`.

I'm always doing that, and there are even codes that finishes like that:

```
var element       = this,
    elementParent = this.parentNode,
    elementIWant  = selectedSpan.parentNode.querySelector('.class');
```

**I dont see it like a good practice.** Is it? I don't see it in other developers' code. I did it with jQuery (`parent()`, `closest()` etc) and JS.

### Is there another approach?

How can I do abstract functions for manipulating DOM the right way? Is that the way people do?

Answer (score 1):

The logic to get a value from an input field and put that value into a target element must assume some kind of DOM structure exists (as in your example) if the target element is not explicitly known.

A convention that I often use is adding a data- (data dash) attribute to the input field to store the id of the target element that will be updated with the input value. For example:

```
<div>
  <label for="filename">Filename: </label>
  <input type="text" id="filename" data-target-id="filename-display" />
</div>
<div class="some-displayed-values">
  <span class="input" id="filename-display"></span>
</div>
```

Then, the target element can be selected by its ID value, like so:

```
function setFilename () {
  var input = this;

  // older browsers might not have input.dataset available
  var targetId = input.dataset.targetId || input.getAttribute('data-target-id'); 

  var target = document.getElementById(targetId);
  target.innerHTML = input.value;
}
```

Example on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/silkster/ex1dvv0s/

Comment: As @Oriol suggested, you should check target to make sure it exists before trying to set its innerHTML.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to access the parent, `parentNode` or `parentElement` are the right ways.

If other developers don't use them, it may be because they don't want to access the parent.

However, be aware that

- `parentNode` may return a node instead of an element. So using properties or methods only available to elements on the returned value may throw. If you expect the result to be an element, use `parentElement` instead.
- Both `parentNode` and `parentElement` may return `null`. So it may be a good idea to check the returned value before attempting to access its properties.